# Can I use other helpers methods in application_helper.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I have a question about the availability of methods defined in `app/helpers`.

Can I share methods in helpers, (for example, use methods defined in `my_helper.rb` in `application_helper.rb`), or are they restricted to views ?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do that if you have this in controller or application_controller:

```
helper :all
```

But it seems a little too complex to have helpers that call out to other helpers, generally helper methods should be short simple and have little dependencies, they should do one simple thing for the view, each. Makes it harder to test I suppose if you have helper methods that call out to other helpers.

If the problem you are trying to solve with this is sufficiently complex I'd suggest trying to move it to a module in the lib directory and then include that module in the helpers that need the common functionality.

Comment: I understand that calling the helper :all causes including to application_helper.rb all the other helpers, then application_helper.rb is appended to each view. All methods in all helpers are available in every view and every helper?

Comment: Have you tried it? Either it works or it doesn't work. I sometimes include some helper functionality into my controller classes like this  "include MyFooHelper". You should be able to do that in any class you want to use a helper in.